# Maximum and minimum of an integral under integral constraints.

Tags: calculus, probability-distributions, optimization, linear-programming, calculus-of-variations

Find the maximum and minimum of the following integral in terms of $f(x),a,C$:
\begin{align}I=\int_{0}^{a} \frac{x}{f(x)}p(x)dx  \end{align}
s.t.:
1) $\int_{0}^{a} p(x)dx=1$
2) $\int_{0}^{a} f(x)p(x)dx=C$

Notes:
1) $p(x)$ is an unknown probability density function.
2) $x,f(x),p(x)\geq 0 \;,\; C>0$
3) $f(0)=0$
4) $\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{x}{f(x)}=0$

Comment: Are we allowed to make addtional hypotheses on $f$? For example, continuity, integrability, etc?

Comment: Yes, you are allowed to assume $f(x)$ as a continuous, differentiable, integrable function.

Comment: I have tried some methods in calculus of variations, like Lagrangian multipliers and methods in isoperimetric problems. While I am not sure that I have used those methods correctly, I would like to now if there is any other analytic solution.

Comment: Are you searching for $p$ or $f$? Which is it?