# Extrema of a vector norm under two inner-product constraints.

Tags: optimization, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, vector-analysis, inner-products

If $\langle\vec{A},\vec{V}\rangle=1\; ,\;  \langle\vec{B},\vec{V}\rangle=c$, then:
\begin{align} max\left \| \vec{V} \right \|_{1}=?\;\;\;min\left \| \vec{V} \right \|_{1}=? \end{align}
Consider the entry-wise norm.
All of the arrays are positive.
Express the extrema in terms of $\vec{A}$, $\vec{B}$ and $c$.

Comment: Do you mean $\langle A, V\rangle$?

Comment: Yes, I exactly mean that (entry-wise product). I will correct it right now.

Comment: Without additional information about $A$ and $B$ you can't conclude anything about $\|V\|_1$ other that $\|V\|_1\neq 0$.

Comment: Please look at the question below, I tried to ask this question in discrete form. With MATLAB you can find the answers.:
http://math.stackexchange.com/q/457500/88652

Comment: And please notice that you are allowed to response in terms of A and B.

Comment: By entrywise norm do you mean $\|(v_1, ..., v_n)\|_1=\sum_{i=1}^n|v_i|$?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Here you can work without absolute values, because the arrays are positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't get any control on the max. Consider $A=(1, 0)$ and $B=(c, 0)$ then any $V=(1, r)$ for $r\in\mathbb{R}^+$ satisfies this, and $\|V\|_1$ of such a $V$ can be arbitrarily large.

You do get control over min.

min$\|V\|_1=max\left\{\frac{1}{\|A\|_2}, \frac{c}{\|B\|_2}\right\}$.
To see this first recall that $\|V\|_2=\sqrt{\langle V, V\rangle}$, then note that for all vectors, $V$, of a given $\|\cdot\|_2$-norm, the one with the largest value of $\langle A, V\rangle$ are the ones of the form $kA$ where $k$ is a scalar. So to minimize the norm that satisfies $\langle A, V\rangle=1$ we choose $V=\frac{1}{\|A\|_2}A$, a similar argument works with $B$. So you get that $\|V\|_2$ has to be bigger than both of those terms in the max. Since $\|V\|_2\leq\|V\|_1$, you get the same bound on $V$. Choosing A, B, and V as in the above example shows that this bound is realized and thus is the min.